# Requests to a localhost server running SparkJava work using postman, but not with javascript in a browser

Tags: javascript, java, xmlhttprequest, cors, spark-java

I have this simple server running from eclipse using the SparkJava API:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    staticFileLocation("/public");
    port(5678);
    enableCORS("*", "*", "*");

    get("/hello", (request, response) -> "Hello World!");

    post("/hello", (request, response) ->
        "Hello World: " + request.body()
    );
}



private static void enableCORS(final String origin, final String methods, final String headers) {

    options("/*", (request, response) -> {

        String accessControlRequestHeaders = request.headers("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        if (accessControlRequestHeaders != null) {
            response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", accessControlRequestHeaders);
        }

        String accessControlRequestMethod = request.headers("Access-Control-Request-Method");
        if (accessControlRequestMethod != null) {
            response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", accessControlRequestMethod);
        }

        return "OK";
    });

    before((request, response) -> {
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        response.header("Access-Control-Request-Method", methods);
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers);
        // Note: this may or may not be necessary in your particular application
        response.type("application/json");
    });
}
```

And I have this Javascript running from a webpage:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "localhost:5678/hello", true);
var test = oReq.send("TESTING");
document.getElementById("TEST").innerHTML = test;
```

I can send requests and get a response when I send them through the Postman chrome app, but when I run this script in chrome, I get the following error:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:5678/hello. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.*

I've tried running the script in Firefox and Edge as well, but I still get a network error. Why would the requests work in Postman but not when running a script from any browsers?

Comment: It works through Postman because you are directly calling the server. There is no CORS involved here. But when you do it through javascript CORS comes into play. I see you have added the respective headers. That should solve the problem. But the req url doesn't contain http scheme. You need to change `localhost:5678/hello` to `http://localhost:5678/hello`.

Comment: @yaswanth Thank you! That solved it, I can't believe I missed something so simple.

Comment: Let me add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works through Postman because you are directly calling the server. There is no CORS involved here. But when you do it through javascript CORS comes into play. I see you have added the respective headers. That should solve the problem. But the req url doesn't contain http scheme. You need to change `localhost:5678/hello` to `http://localhost:5678/hello`